# Why in C++ extra method qualification is not allowed?

Tags: c++

Is there a reason we can not write in C++

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    void MyClass::MyMethod();  // <----
}
```

it gives 'extra qualification' or some such compile error but is there a reason for that or it's just so happened?

Comment: Because that's how the language is defined.  Why would you want to do that?

Comment: What is your intention?

Comment: Its a reasonable question, and 2nd paragraph of Mike Seymour's reply gives an answer.

Comment: Strange that my question got so many downvotes and close requests. 'Because that's how the language is defined' hmm... because God has said so... Normally they have a good reason beyond every grammatical decision.

Comment: I would not WANT to do that I did that once by mistake and then I thought but it's a tautology, why it's forbidden then. Anyway, the question has now been answered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because that's the syntax for declarations; they declare an *unqualified* name to have a particular meaning within the scope of the declaration.

If a scope qualification were allowed, it would always be either redundant (specifying the current scope) or wrong (since you can't declare something in another scope).

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that it is illegal syntax. Besides, why would you need to add a redundant extra qualification?

The member function is being declared in the context of the class definition, explicitly qualifying it as a member function of that class is unnecessary - and it compromises readability.